# Postfix send bcc based on mail content

Tags: postfix

I know about body_checks directive in postfix and i tried to do the following in my pcre:/etc/postfix/body_check

```
/some string/ BCC foo@bar.com
```

But it is not working. Action BCC cannot probably be here. Is there any solution to this? Send blind copy of email if it contains specific string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by reversing your logic: set up always_bcc to deliver to a specified filtering recipient, and then check for the string in the body.

Of course, the amount of extra traffic you will generate is significant (you're going to double the number of messages sent), but you can't use always_bcc with internally-generated mail; postfix will refuse to copy them to prevent routing loops.